# Insert post in wordpress in category specified by theme

Tags: php, wordpress, post, categories

Hi I have my code below so when I insert post everything is ok but my post is uncategorised. Can someone tell me how to insert it in right category ? I have category under ID 416. I have tested it with multiple wordpress versions.

```
<form id='login'  method = "post" accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='title' >naziv*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='title' id='title'  maxlength="50" /><br/>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='content' >tekst*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='content' id='content'  maxlength="50" /><br/>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='cena' >cena*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='cena' id='cena'  maxlength="50" /><br/>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <label for='user' >user*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='user' id='user'  maxlength="50" /><br/>
</div>


<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit' />
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
<?php
require_once '../wp-load.php';
require_once '../wp-includes/pluggable.php';
require_once '../wp-includes/post-thumbnail-template.php';
require_once '../wp-includes/media.php';
$odgovor = array();
require_once '../wp-load.php';
require_once '../wp-includes/pluggable.php';
 function funkcija_unos(){
if(isset ($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['content']) && isset($_POST['user']))
{
     $odgovor["success"] = 0;
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $_POST['user'] );
$id = array(
    'post_title'    => $_POST['title'],
    'post_content'  => $_POST['content'],
    'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author'   => $user->ID,
    'taxonomy' => ('cate'),
    'post_type'     => 'ad',
    'post_category' => array(416),
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
); 
 $user_id = wp_insert_post($id);
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
   $odgovor["success"] = 1;
}
    echo json_encode($odgovor);
}
}
if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){ funkcija_unos();}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**'post_category'** not work with Custom Taxonomies and **'taxonomy**' param does not exist. 
You should use **'tax_input'** param. 
 Like this:

```
$id = array(
    'post_title'    => $_POST['title'],
    'post_content'  => $_POST['content'],
    'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author'   => $user->ID,
    'post_type'     => 'ad',
    'tax_input' => array( 'cate' => array(416) ),
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
);
```

See [doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

Comment: Thank you I will try it as soon is possible. I found another code that works for this `$user_id = wp_insert_post($id);
     wp_set_object_terms($user_id, 2, 'cate', true);`  @Luan Cuba

Comment: Yeah! This works too... any doubt, I'm here! @StefanJovanic